# Speed up Oracle SQL Developer query in large Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am querying an Oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer. The query is running slowly. I am away that using Distinct is likely slowing me down. But I haven't been able to produce unique rows without the Distinct call.  The database contains no duplicate rows. So, it is likely that I malformed this query. How do I speed up this query? The query is as follows:

````
SELECT DISTINCT 
    view1.table1.col1, 
    view1.table2.col2, 
    view1.table2.col3, 
    view1.table1.col4, 
    view1.table3.col5, 
    view1.table4.col6 
FROM 
    view1.table1, 
    view1.table3, 
    view1.table2, 
    view1.table4
WHERE 
    table1.col1 = table2.col7
AND
    table1.col4 = table3.col8
AND
    table1.col4 >= '19-DEC-20'
AND 
    table4.col9 = table3.col10 ```
````

Comment: "SQL Developer" is irrelevant; what is slow is the execution of your query on the database server. SQL Developer has nothing to do with that. Then: you have the condition `col4 >= '19-DEC-20'`. `col4` from which table? And are you comparing strings, or dates? If it's dates, why do you have a string on the right-hand side? As for performance - what does the explain plan show? What indexes do you have on any of the tables involved in the query? (And - do you really have a schema named **view1**? That's quite odd.)

Comment: you're joining 4 VIEWs or tables?...and if views, then gosh knows what those VIEWs are actually doing. Also, most people using DISTINCT don't actually need to or have a bad data model. First thing I would do is look at your execution plan

Comment: I don't see any join criteria for `view1.table4`  so you end up with a cartesian join, which may return thousands or million rows.  I know a "friend" that did that 30+ years ago, and he waited over 24 hours, then killed the query.

Comment: @MarkStewart: errors like that can easily be avoided by switching to the "modern" (30 years old) explicit JOIN operators

Comment: Yeah, @a_horse_with_no_name, that friend did that on IBM DB2, and he still is in the same bad habit with Oracle 19.  So I hear.

Comment: @MarkStewart I corrected the join. It was correctly done in the original. I messed up one digit when transcribing the names from their original names to these vague names. thatjeffsmith and mathguy I will post the explain plan results after they complete.

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

```
table1:  INDEX(col4, col1)
table3:  INDEX(col8, col5, col10)
table2:  INDEX(col7, col2, col3)
table4:  INDEX(col9, col6)
```

Comment: Nice answer, based on initial question. Rick basically suggested indexes on columns that were join columns or were one of SELECTed columns, to allow Oracle to just read the indexes to derive the results.  Note that the order of the columns of the indexes may need to be altered, depending on column statistics, and number of rows.  And if there are views in the query instead of tables, or adding an index is not feasible, ... need the explain plan at least.  Impact of indexes on storage and performance may be an issue too.

Comment: I think that shuffling the columns in each index will make things worse.  (I agree what VIEWs throw a monkey wrench in.)